# MYSQL - Use variable with Regex in select query to get records

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

There are strings in table

```
+1-123-456-7890 
11234567890
+1 1234567890
1777555999
```

I have variable `$phoneNumber`. I want to pass variable in sql query to get matching records.
example:
`$phoneNumber` holds the value `1234567890`
and using same variable I want to fetch  following records in one query

```
+1-123-456-7890 
11234567890
+1 1234567890
```

I want to select both records in one query.
how can I match data (11234567890) with above saved numbers?

Comment: what MySQL Regex pattern have you tried?

Comment: `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(telephone, ' ', ''), '+', ''), '-', '') LIKE $telephone`

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Now your question is not clear.  Which of the three sample numbers should be matched here?  After removing `+`, `-`, and spaces, only the middle number is an exact match.

Comment: +1-123-456-7890 
    11234567890
    +1 1234567890

These numbers should be returned every time when `$phoneNumber` value is any of the following
     
    +1-123-456-7890 
    11234567890
    +1 1234567890

all number should be treated as same because they have same number if ' ', '-', '+' characters not considered.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this following the replacement logic already suggested here combined with regular expressions, to match only the phone numbers with the format you want to target:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '+1-123-456-7890' AS phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '+1 1234567890' UNION ALL
    SELECT '+6512345678'
)

SELECT
    phone,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone, ' ', ''), '+', ''), '-', '') AS common_phone
FROM yourTable
WHERE phone REGEXP '\\+[0-9][[:space:]-][0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}';
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I am looking for something like this.

`select phone from myTable where phone like '{some regex pattern which can filter with the value of variable $phoneNumber}'; `

Here $phoneNumber can be any pattern with '+' and '-' or just number.

Comment: What issues would there be in adapting my raw MySQL query to PHP code?

Comment: How can I compare a variable with the table data to filter the results? above query will return results only matching to pattern. It will ignore number like this '11234567890'


WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '11234567890' AS phone UNION ALL
    SELECT '+1 1234567890' UNION ALL
    SELECT '+6512345678'
)

SELECT
    phone,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone, ' ', ''), '+', ''), '-', '') AS common_phone
FROM yourTable
WHERE phone REGEXP '\\+[0-9][[:space:]-][0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}';

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  If your requirements have changed, or I missed something, then edit your question and add more information.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

**Regex :**

```
 [\+]?[0-9](?:[-| ])?\d{3}[-]?\d{3}[-]?\d{4}
```

**Verify through regxe101:**

[image]

Comment: Your regex pattern can't be used in a MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If both `$phonenumber` and your string column could (potentially) both have the troublesome characters, this is hard to solve with regular expressions.

```
where replace(replace(replace($phonenumber, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '+') = replace(replace(replace(phonecol, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '+')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I solved this with something similar query.
I removed special characters from variable `$phoneNumber` and compared it with the string result of the replace.

`SELECT phone FROM myTable where REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone, ' ', ''), '+', ''), '-', '') = $phoneNumber;`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with using `replace()` in query. 
I removed special characters from variable `$phoneNumber` (not through sql but before passing varable to sql) and compared it with the string result of the replace. `SELECT phone FROM myTable where REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone, ' ', ''), '+', ''), '-', '') = $phoneNumber;`

Answer (score 0):

Rethink the overall design.

Cleanse phone numbers *before* putting them into the table.  Then that `SELECT`, and the other `SELECTs` that are yet to be written, will be simple.